# test isolation between pytest-hypothesis runs

Tags: python, pytest, quickcheck, python-hypothesis

I just migrated a pytest test suite from `quickcheck` to `hypothesis`. This worked quite well (and immediately uncovered some hidden edge case bugs), but one major difference I see is related to test isolation between the two property managers.

`quickcheck` seems to simply run the test function multiple times with different parameter values, each time running my function-scoped fixtures. This also results in many more dots in pytest's output.

`hypothesis` however seems to run only the body of the test function multiple times, meaning for example no transaction rollbacks between individual runs. This then means I cannot reliably assert for a number of DB entries when my test inserts something into the DB for example, since all the entries from the previous run would still be hanging around.

Am I missing something obvious here or is this expected behaviour? If so, is there a way to get the number of runs hypothesis has done as a variable to use inside the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you're a bit stuck and there isn't currently any good solution to this problem.

The way Hypothesis needs to work (which is the source of a lot of its improvements over pytest-quickcheck) doesn't meet pytest's assumptions about test execution. The problem is [mostly on the pytest side](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/916) - the current pytest fixture system has some very baked in assumptions about how you run a test that do not play well with taking control of the test execution, and the last time I tried to work around this I ended up sinking about a week of work into it before giving up and basically saying that either something needs to change on the pytest side or [someone needs to fund this work](http://hypothesis.works/articles/pytest-integration-sponsorship/) if it's going to get any better.

Comment: I see. Thank you for taking the time to answer. I am currently managing to work around this, by taking this into account in my asserts. In fact, it also has some advantages to it. :-)

By the way, is there perhaps a way to get the number of runs hypothesis has done as a variable to use inside the test?

Thanks again!